# What is difference between `flag is TRUE` vs `flag = TRUE` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I ran the following queries in MySQL -

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE valid is TRUE
ORDER BY priority DESC 
limit 10 
offset 0;
```

Time taken = 1 second.

vs

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE valid = TRUE 
ORDER BY priority DESC 
limit 10 
offset 0;
```

Time taken = 66 ms.

I have indexes on (valid, priority) and (valid).
Why is there such a huge difference?
What is the difference between **Is TRUE** vs **= TRUE** ?

Comment: Remember, you can always execute `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query]` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;` to gain more insight into what's going on 'under the hood'

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. I was only using `EXPLAIN` till now.

Comment: Avoid `IS` except when testing against `NULL`.  The mind-warping Answers here explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Mysql [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is) for IS operator

IS boolean_value

> Tests a value against a boolean value, where boolean_value can be TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.

In SQL, a boolean_value – either TRUE , FALSE or UNKNOWN – is a truth value. When using IS operator, the value you are testing against must be expressed/cast as one of these truth values, and then the expression is evaluated.

---

**In your first query:**

`SELECT * from table WHERE valid is TRUE ORDER BY priority DESC  limit 10  offset 0;`

depending on the datatype of the valid column, the truth value is evaluated for each row which would result in a full table scan, hence you would see higher times.

---

**In your second query:**

`SELECT * from table WHERE valid = TRUE  ORDER BY priority DESC  limit 10  offset 0;`

when you use = operator, you are comparing the valid column to [Boolean Literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html) TRUE, which is just a MySQL constant for 1.

Comment: So it sounds like `IS` is similar to `===` in javascript, but specifically for `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`

Comment: @Evert That would not be the correct way to interpret it. For eg, `5 === 'TRUE'` in javascript gives false, while `SELECT 5 IS TRUE` in myql outputs 1, which means true.

Comment: Phrased differently, MySQL does not have anything directly equivalent to `===`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very important difference:

- `IS TRUE` only trues "true" or "false"
- `= TRUE` can return `NULL`.

In particular `NULL IS TRUE` returns "false".

Actually, this is not so important for `IS TRUE`.  It is a substantial difference for `IS NOT TRUE` versus `NOT` or `<> true`.

That is `IS TRUE` and `IS NOT TRUE` is "NULL-safe":

```
where NULL IS NOT TRUE  --> evaluates to true and all rows are returned
where NOT NULL          --> evaluates to NULL and no rows are returned
where NULL <> TRUE      --> evaluates to NULL and no rows are returned
```

The `NULL` here could be an expression that returns a `NULL` values.

These semantics are clearly explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is).

Comment: `NULL IS TRUE` formally evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. When `UNKNOWN` is returned to the client app is silently converted to `false`. SQL defines trivalent logic since its inception.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . This is easily checked by running the code:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=870a93e8b6f099a5b1e4d3c1ea783ee8.  Your comment is incorrect.  The documentation is also explicit on this point, which I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic difference between the two.

1. The IS operator serves as a way to test against a certain value as to whether it is true, false or unknown.

From documentation:
  `IS boolean_value`

Tests a value against a boolean value, where boolean_value can be TRUE, FALSE,    or UNKNOWN.

mysql> SELECT 1 IS TRUE, 0 IS FALSE, NULL IS UNKNOWN;
-> 1, 1, 1

For the "=" operator, it is merely a way to equate something to compare. In your query, you are using valid to be set to True.

So, depending on your use case, you would use the operators. In your current query, they look as if they do the same thing.